# How do I show woocommerce sortby/orderby dropdown menu in custom wp_query?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

This is my query:

```
***
```

> $args = array(
> 'post_type'             => 'product',
> 'post_status'           => 'publish',
> 'posts_per_page'        => 12,
> 'paged'                 => $paged,
> );
>
> ```
> $loop = new WP_Query($args);
> ```

---

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. Give us a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be sure to take the tour and read this.

Comment: My bad...this is my first question here :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to make a custom sortBy dropdown.
This is how I solved it:

```
<?php
    $orderby = 'ID';
    $order = 'DESC';
    if (isset($_GET['orderby']) && $_GET['orderby'] != "") {
        $order_by = $_GET['orderby'];
        WC()->query->remove_ordering_args();
        if ($order_by == 'title-desc') {
            $orderby = 'title';
            $order = 'DESC';
        }
        if ($order_by == 'title-asc') {
            $orderby = 'title';
            $order = 'ASC';
        }
        if ($order_by == 'price-asc') {
            $meta_key = '_price';
            $orderby  = ['meta_value_num' => 'ASC', $order => 'ASC'];
        }
        if ($order_by == 'price-desc') {
            $meta_key = '_price';
            $orderby  = ['meta_value_num' => 'DESC', $order => 'DESC'];
        }
        if ($order_by == 'date-asc') {
            $orderby = 'ID';
            $order = 'ASC';
        }
        if ($order_by == 'date-desc') {
            $orderby = 'ID';
            $order = 'DESC';
        }
    }
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    if ($meta_key == '_price') {
        $args = array(
            'post_type'             => 'product',
            'post_status'           => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page'        => 12,
            'paged'                 => $paged,
            'orderby'               => $orderby,
            'order'                 => $order,
            'meta_key'              => $meta_key,
        );
    } else {
        $args = array(
            'post_type'             => 'product',
            'post_status'           => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page'        => 12,
            'paged'                 => $paged,
            'orderby'               => $orderby,
            'order'                 => $order,
        );
    }



    $loop = new WP_Query($args);
    // debug($loop);
    ?>
```

And this is my form:

```
<form class="woocommerce-ordering" method="get">
                            <select name="orderby" class="orderby form-select" aria-label="Shop order"
                                onchange="this.form.submit()">
                                <option <?php if (isset($order_by) && $orderby == 'ID' && isset($order) && $order == 'DESC') {
                                            echo 'selected';
                                        } ?> value="date-desc">Sort by latest
                                </option>

                                <option <?php if (isset($order_by) && $orderby == 'ID' && isset($order) && $order == 'ASC') {
                                            echo 'selected';
                                        } ?> value="date-asc">Sort by oldest
                                </option>

                                <option <?php if (isset($order_by) && $orderby == 'title' && isset($order) && $order == 'ASC') {
                                            echo 'selected';
                                        } ?> value="title-asc">Sort by name: a to z
                                </option>

                                <option <?php if (isset($order_by) && $orderby == 'title' && isset($order) && $order == 'DESC') {
                                            echo 'selected';
                                        } ?> value="title-desc">Sort by name: z to a
                                </option>

                                <option <?php if (isset($order_by) && $orderby == ['meta_value_num' => 'ASC', $order => 'ASC'] && isset($meta_key) && $meta_key == '_price') {
                                            echo 'selected';
                                        } ?> value="price-asc">Sort by price: low to high
                                </option>

                                <option <?php if (isset($order_by) && $orderby == ['meta_value_num' => 'DESC', $order => 'DESC']  && isset($meta_key) && $meta_key == '_price') {
                                            echo 'selected';
                                        } ?> value="price-desc">Sort by price: high to low
                                </option>
                            </select>
                        </form>
```